# How to perform operation after each line for python tokenizer

Tags: python

I'm using python [tokenize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) module to process a python source file. The code looks like below:

```
raw_list = []
words_list = []
g = tokenize.generate_tokens(file.readline)
for toknum, tokval, _, _, line in g:
    if toknum == tokenize.NAME and tokval not in PYTHON_KEYWORD:
        words_list.append(tokval)
```

I know I can reference current line using `line` variable. I want to append `words_list` to `raw_list` after each line. How can I do that? Specifically, how can I perform append action each time after the `line` value changed?

I'm thinking of using `next` method but I don't see any clean way to do it.

For example,

Suppose my input source file contains only one line:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

and there are four tokens: `from`, `__future__`, `import`, and `print_function`. Right now, with `g`, for each token, there will be 5-tuple returned, namely "token type", "token string", "(srow, scol)", "(erow, ecol)". For example, token `__future__` will have

```
NAME, (1,2), (1,5), "from __future__ import print_function"
```

`"from __future__ import print_function"` will be read into variable `line`. Now, both `__future__` and `print_function` will have `line` variable set to
`"from __future__ import print_function"`. Only `__future__` and `print_function` are not python reserved keywords and thus `words_list` will end up with `['__future__', 'print_function']`.

My question is how can I append `words_list` to `raw_list` only when `line` value changed (i.e., the next line string).

Thanks!

Comment: `raw_list.append(word_list)`??? Maybe initialize `word_list` inside the loop?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I tried to append `word_list` whenever I reach a different `line`. I certainly don't want to append every time.

Comment: ... what do you mean? Each iteration is a different line, so append at the end of each iteration, no? Perhaps it would easy if you made some dummy source-code, and you could show us the input/expected output, or else this tends to go back-and-forth in a confusing way wihtout a concrete example to talk about

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Not necessary. For instance `from __future__ import print_function` will have 4 tokens `from`, `__future__`, `import`, and `print_function`. However, they all belong to the same line with same `line` value. So, I want to append when I see all these 4 tokens.

Comment: I see now what you are saying.

Comment: Hmm, what about checking for `type=4 (NEWLINE)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That works! Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for @[juanpa.arrivillaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5014455/juanpa-arrivillaga) wonderful answer. Explicitly check `tokenize.NEWLINE` works. The code looks like below:

```
raw_list = []
words_list = []
g = tokenize.generate_tokens(file.readline)
for toknum, tokval, _, _, line in g:
    if toknum == tokenize.NAME and tokval not in PYTHON_KEYWORD:
        words_list.append(tokval)
    if toknum == tokenize.NEWLINE:
        raw_list.append(words_list)
        words_list = []
```